# HttpListner discovery

Tags: xamarin, self-hosting, httplistener

I'm developing a system on Xamain in a way that each device can create network service via HttpListner then start listing for incoming calls from other devices on same LAN network. Upon creating the listner we can apply naming convention in the URI so that other devices can filterout non-related services.

The question is there a way to discover all hosts (ip+port) under same LAN having given service's prefix?

I could do it using device specific code for Android via NdsManager class then calling DiscoveringPeers() but I'm thinking why it's not possible to have equivalent functionality in .Net?

Comment: Assuming local lan, you could use `UdpClient` and make each device a client & server and each client broadcasts to 255.255.255.255 with a "message", each "server" receives the "message" (assuming it contains URI filter, port, ..) and thus each server knows the IP address of the client from the `IPEndPoint` response, the port that the "client" HttpListener is on, etc... Just Google|Bing ".net broadcast discovery using udp" and you will find many examples, there are libraries on Github that help automate all of that also.

Comment: Instead of inventing your own wheel, ZeroConf is there, based on Bonjour from Apple and work cross platform, https://github.com/onovotny/Zeroconf

Comment: ZeroConf is one of the ones on Github, it is another UdpClient-based implementation on mDNS/Bonjour

Answer (score 0):

I used ZeroConf as source of inspiration to implement Multicasting clients and now all good. The most important is picking up the right Ip address adapted to your Network to multicast. See this table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address). 
Broadcasting to 255.255.255.255 was not the required behavior as well as it will not be routed.